# Using string list as Chart.js label

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, chart.js

I need to create a chart with two lists.

```
List<string> islemYapanOperatorler = new List<string>();
    List<int> interventionCounter = new List<int>();
        foreach (var item in itemList)
    {
        string Normalize = item.Key;
        for (int i = 0; i < turkishChars.Length; i++)
            Normalize = Normalize.Replace(turkishChars[i], englishChars[i]);
        islemYapanOperatorler.Add(Normalize);
        foreach (var item2 in item)
        {
            interventionCount++;
        }
        interventionCounter.Add(interventionCount);
        interventionCount = 0;
        operatorCount++;
    }
```

islemYapanOperatorler list is creates the label part and interventioncounter list is creating the data part for Chart.Js.

And javascript code for Chart.js below: (It's a bit lazy but it gives the result I want.)

```
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels:
               ['@islemYapanOperatorler[0]', '@islemYapanOperatorler[1]', '@islemYapanOperatorler[2]', '@islemYapanOperatorler[3]', '@islemYapanOperatorler[4]', '@islemYapanOperatorler[5]', '@islemYapanOperatorler[6]', '@islemYapanOperatorler[7]', '@islemYapanOperatorler[8]', '@islemYapanOperatorler[9]', '@islemYapanOperatorler[10]']

                ,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Haftalık',
                data: [@interventionCounter[0], @interventionCounter[1], @interventionCounter[2], @interventionCounter[3], @interventionCounter[4], @interventionCounter[5], @interventionCounter[6], @interventionCounter[7], @interventionCounter[8], @interventionCounter[9], @interventionCounter[10]],
                backgroundColor: [

                    'rgba(0, 26, 190, 0.8)'
                ],
                borderColor: [

                    'rgba(0, 26, 190, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }

            ]
        },
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                        return data['labels'][tooltipItem['index']] + ': ' + data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']] ;
                    }
                }
            },

            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

It's working correctly and gives the result I want. (picture below)
[image]

But, as you can see

It works fine for 11 indices, but this number of indices may vary. In such a case, either it does not show the data in the 12th index because it is defined as a constant 11 index, or it fails because the 11th index is empty.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deep research:

```
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(interventionCounter));
    var monthlyData = [];
    $.each(model, function (index, item) {
        monthlyData .push(item.toString());
    });
```

then at the Chartjs script:

```
data: monthlyData,
```

solved my question. I'm marking this answer in order to help others in the future.